# ros remap what is the difference between ~ and /?

Tags: ros

I came across with this statement in ros code and I am not sure what it is and why ?

What are "~" and "/" ?

Thanks

I would like to know what they are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are different [`names`](http://wiki.ros.org/Names). This is a way to create a hierarchical naming structure.

From the referenced page:

> Names that start with a "/" are global -- they are considered fully resolved. Global names should be avoided as much as possible as they limit code portability.

> Names that start with a "~" are private. They convert the node's name into a namespace. For example, node1 in namespace /wg/ has the private namespace /wg/node1. Private names are useful for passing parameters to a specific node via the parameter server.

In short, if a node `my_node` publishes a topic as `/topic` it will be available as `/topic`. If the same node publishes as `~/topic` instead, it will be available as `/my_node/topic`. The same would apply for parameters